# Django i18n uses its own translations

Tags: django, internationalization

I have started internationalization of my app and faced 2 problems.

First, I have created a .po file for pl locale and translated all the strings. Everything works allright except for "Log in" string. I translated "Log in" into "Zaloguj" but in HTML it appears as "Zaloguj się" though such translation doesn't even exist in .po file. I suppose "Log in" is such popular that Django provides out-of-the-box translation (like for error messages) but is it documented anywhere? Also, it's strange that I can't manage to use my translation instead of it.

Secondly, I have internationalizaed error messages (I use my own user model):

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['email', 'password', 'name']
        error_messages = {
            'email': {
                'required': _("Please enter e-mail"),
                'max_length': _("E-mail address can be %(limit_value)s characters long"),
                'invalid': _("E-mail address is invalid")
            },
            'password': {
                'required': _("Please enter password")
            },
            'name': {
                'required': _("Please enter full name"),
                'max_length': _("Full name can be %(limit_value)s characters long")
            }
        }
```

The strange thing here is that messages aren't translated. When I hit my app with en locale set it's okay, I see my custom error messages but when I change it to pl I don't see polish equivalents (thought they exist in .po file). Why is it?

**P.S.**

I have done stuff like "django-admin.py compilemessages", restared server, restarted computer and nothing worked. It must be something in Django. I use 1.6 version.

Comment: Does django detect your "change to polish" ? I know it's too obvious but, could you check for your active language ? When the text has to be in polish, check if the active language is polish. Did you make "translation.activate('pl')" ? [Explicity setting the active language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I made a wrong import:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

should be

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

The lazy version is correct when using in class field declaration. I hope it will help somebody in future